# Graceful improvement (not degration) with Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, jekyll, graceful-degradation

We're relaunching the landing page of our company (contains an info, jobs, team and help section) and decided we'll no longer maintain a Rails project only for this part of our service and therefore switch to static HTML.

As we want to give our HR and support team the chance to edit the texts (especially in the jobs and help section) without bugging the dev team, we'll get an Angular.js app running on the page and patch in the content using a JSON APi (like the one Wordpress.com offers http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/ or we might even use https://www.contentful.com/).

However, as we need our landing page to load really fast (conversion is king), we're thinking of serving the initial part of our landing page as static HTML and gracefully add Angular.js after the user has access to the most important information. We don't care if people with deactivated JS can't use the rest of our page, therefore we'd call this process graceful improvement.

Are there any best practices and/or Angular.js modules out there for achieving what I just described? What's the right terminology for this effect?

P.S.: We'll take care of SEO by rendering the rest of our landing page (team, jobs, etc.) using Phantom.js, therefore SEO is not a topic. It's only about the loading speed of the initial part of our landing page.

Comment: phantomjs is a headless browser, how is that going to help with SEO?

Comment: We'll use Phantom.js to render the different parts of the Angular.js app to static HTML pages which we'll serve to search engines. Pretty much like described in this blog post: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html

Comment: Got it. Answering some suggestions.

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately I don't think you'll find an easy way to fix this problem with Angular, because Angular needs to compile all the templates in order to setup binding and all the functionality. You could possibly have something which would output the main page with the angular ready markup but yeah, that would be a bit of extra work and not out of the box.

Comment: Another possible solution would be to use something which doesn't depend so much on specific markup, like ReactJS. I did a talk on this subject recently (https://github.com/trodrigues/js-pe-slides) and you can check Pete's talk from jsconf.eu as well (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x7cQ3mrcKaY). I was actually trying to build a demo app using this and contentful (disclaimer: I work for contentful), but unfortunately their example middleware for server rendering, which also loads other JS modules, doesn't yet play well with everything.

Answer (score 2):

You could render the static page (whichever way you want to produce those) and add an event listener after the page is loaded. Then in the event listener, you could leverage [angular.bootstrap](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.bootstrap) to start the app manually. That way Angular can take its sweet time about it and not bog down the user.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I was also thinking in this direction, however, there are two problems I see:

#1: User who visit www.company.com/help/me/ should get in touch with Angular.js immediately as there is no routing in place on server level.

We can work around this by checking the content of document.URL and loading Angular.js before page ready in case the user is not on index. But is there a better way?

#2: How can I tell Angular.js not to replace the content of ngView after the page is ready but the user is still on index? It should only replace ngView after the user navigates away from index.

Comment: @zerodot a pragmatic solution would be not have angular at all in the index and just in the landing pages. For instance `misite.com` normal static/manual site. Then you can have manual links in the index point to, say, `mysite.com/app/#/help` and `mysite.com/app/#/jobs` where app is the angular mixin application root.

Comment: You're right, this will definitely work, although it takes away a bit of the beauty and makes the whole thing a little more complicated to maintain and deploy. But I'll take it if I don't find a more elegant solution in the next few hours, thanks!